# PowerPoint VBA - Chart Color Based on Data Label in Horizontal Axis

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I am working on a PowerPoint presentation which consists of multiple slides with 4 charts each. I am using horizontal axis labels for quarters and months, which have different bar colors. The issue I am running across is that when I use "Keep Source Formatting and Link Data" for the charts, values are correct however when the labels change (such as a transition in months), the colors are wrong. I figure using VBA through PowerPoint would be a good solution to determine the colors, but I am having challenges that I did not have with Excel. Here is the code:

```
Sub test()

Dim pptChart As Chart
Dim pptChartData As ChartData
Dim pptWorkbook As Object
Dim sld As slide
Dim shp As shape
Dim pt As Point
Dim xv As Variant
Dim i As Integer

For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
For Each shp In sld.Shapes

        i = 0
        For Each xv In Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(1).DataLabel.Text   'cht.chart.seriescollection(1).xvalues
            i = i + 1
            Select Case xv
            Case "1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"
                Set pt = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
                pt.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0)
            Case "YTD"
                Set pt = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
                pt.Interior.Color = RGB(33, 26, 166)
            Case Else
                Set pt = cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(i)
                pt.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            End Select
        Next

Next
Next

Set pptWorkbook = Nothing
Set pptChartData = Nothing
Set pptChart = Nothing

End Sub
```

What I'm trying to do is for each chart, any labels with Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4 will have a red fill for the bar. YTD will be in blue, and everything else will be in green. With Excel, I was able to assign cht as object, but I'm not sure what it is in PowerPoint.

Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you.

[Chart Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBaUW.png)

Comment: For reference, can you add a screenshot of one of your charts?

Comment: Original post edited to include a link to a screenshot. The chart as mentioned is a copy / paste with "Keep Source Formatting and Link Data." This is created using Office 2013.

Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4 will be red, YTD will be blue, and other will be green. At this time, whenever data is updated and the chart is refreshed, the colors will turn to the wrong ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me. Looping through the `DataLabels` would not work, since they show the values (3.2, 4.1, etc.) Instead, you can loop through the `CategoryNames` of your axis.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim cht As Chart
    Dim cats As Variant
    Dim j As Integer

    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoChart Then             
                cats = shp.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).CategoryNames

                For j = LBound(cats) To UBound(cats)
                    With shp.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Points(j).Format.Fill.ForeColor
                        Select Case cats(j)
                            Case "1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"
                                .RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
                            Case "YTD"
                                .RGB = RGB(33, 26, 166)
                            Case Else
                                .RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        End Select
                    End With
                Next j
            End If
        Next shp
    Next sld
End Sub
```

[image][image]